Name of the arrow icons that tell you there is a subdirectory in a menu?
I don't know how exactly to describe it verbally,
but I just mean the white triangular arrows in this example image: 

In an icon theme that I'm trying to use they either don't exist or are the exact same color as the menus that they're on top of. I don't know how to look up what their standard filename is in GNOME/GTK/whatever icon sets because I also have no idea what they're called in a general sense. 
I just want to go into that theme's folder in /usr/share/icons
and either put them there
or replace them with ones that are actually visible.

I don't think these are icons that you can replace; they are probably just drawn "by hand" as in "draw a filled polygon with corners (0,2), (1,1), (0,0)", or just a character in most fonts.

changing the icon theme is what causes it to happen or not happen. As in, clicking the customize button in Appearance Preferences and going to the icons tab and changing the icons and nothing else, the font never changed. Also if I change to a theme with white menus (in the "controls" tab, leaving the icons tab alone with the same icons selected), then the arrows do appear. So I don't know what else it could be

ah interesting!
